# How to override core catalog block product list?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, blocks, custom

I am trying to override **core/catalog/block/product/List.php** with following

Ref:http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14692/

file: **Ziva/Customcatalog/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ziva_CustomCatalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Ziva_CustomCatalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <class>Ziva_CustomCatalog_Block</class> <!--this is a new block page for that custom module-->
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>Ziva_Customcatalog_Block_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

file: **Ziva/Customcatalog/Block/Product/List.php**

```
class Ziva_Customcatalog_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function _getProductCollection() { // trying to override this method
        echo __CLASS__;
        return parent::_getProductCollection();
    }

    public function holdthis() {
        echo __METHOD__;
    }

}
```

In exception log I am getting

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Ziva_CustomCatalog_Block_Product_Compare_Sidebar' in C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\Mage.php:594
```

followed by

```
Invalid block type: Ziva_CustomCatalog_Block_Product_Price_Template
Invalid block type: Ziva_CustomCatalog_Block_Layer_View
Invalid block type: Ziva_CustomCatalog_Block_Category_View
Invalid block type: Ziva_CustomCatalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
```

And no products are displayed

EDIT:

I figured the problem

```
<class>Ziva_Customcatalog_Block</class>
```

Now I am rephrasing the question.

In a custom module you can only have one block class? But in **core/catalog/block**, we can see many.

Comment: If you only want to add things to the collection I recommend to implement an observer and listen to `catalog_block_product_list_collection`

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: I am trying to limit the number of items in collection. I tried `->setPageSize(10)` but it is not resetting the filters according to the loaded items. It is showing the original filters of the entire collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you update your config.xml as follows, you should be able to add multiple unique handles:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ziva_CustomCatalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Ziva_CustomCatalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <ziva_customcatalog>
                <class>Ziva_CustomCatalog_Block</class> <!--this is a new block page for that custom module-->
            </ziva_customcatalog>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>Ziva_Customcatalog_Block_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

You can then call `'ziva_customcatalog/layer_view'` for your new block.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention:

`<product_list>Ziva_Customcatalog_Block_Product_List</product_list>`

must be in one line without spaces! I became crazy to solve a similar problem!