# Rewrite core classes or override?

Tags: module, magento-1, overrides

I have made a bunch of changes in my local folder to override core classes. But I'd like to group some of them into modules so i can turn them on and off.

I am new to the module creation process. I've copied some code from tutorials online, but one thing I have not been able to answer is whether I should rewrite the core classes (which I am effectively already doing by overriding them in the local folder), or if I should extend them.

My understanding is that in either case, you create a class in your module folder that extends the core class. But in one case you surround in in `<rewrite>` tags and in the other you don't. But I don't know what the difference in effect is.

I need my module to change the behavior of

**These Catalog template files in app/design/frontend/myinterface/mytheme/template/catalog/:**

```
product/list.phtml
product/list/toolbar.phtml
product/view.phtml
```

**These blocks in Catalog/Block/:**

```
Product/List.php
Product/View.php
Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

**These models in Catalog/Model/:**

```
Layer/Filter/Attribute.php
Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php
Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php
```

Again, everything already works, but there is so much that is changed that I would like to package it into a module to make it easier to turn on and off and I want to make sure I go about it the right way.

EDIT:

In case anyone's wondering, the changes I've made are to group products together based on an attribute value. Some values are NULL, though, and those should not be grouped. I needed the filter functionality to display quantities that matched the visible products so that code had to be changed as well as the product list code.

**Edit2:**

After trying copying various online examples, one finally halfway worked, [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10749/2396).
Below xml attempts to load just 2 block files. The `list.php` is loading, but `toolbar.php` is not.

```
<!-- The root node for Magento module configuration -->
<config> 

    <!-- 
        The module's node contains basic 
        information about each Magento module
    --> 
    <modules>

        <!--
            This must exactly match the namespace and module's folder
            names, with directory separators replaced by underscores
        -->
        <Mynamespace_MyModule>

            <!-- The version of our module, starting at 0.0.1 -->
            <version>0.0.1</version>

        </Mynamespace_MyModule>

    </modules>
    <global>
        <models />      
        <blocks>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_MyModule_Block</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        <catalog>
        <rewrite>
                <!-- THEY LOAD! --><product_list>Mynamespace_MyModule_Block_Product_List</product_list>
        <product_list_toolbar>Mynamespace_MyModule_Block_Product_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
        </rewrite>

        </catalog>  
        </blocks>

        <helpers />
    </global>

</config>
```

I got the above XML to work after I realized that I misnamed my extension to the toolbar class.

**Additional Info**

Here is the function I'm overriding in the product resource class (my rewritten version).

```
class Mynamespace_MyModule_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection
{

/**
     * Get SQL for get record count
     *
     * @return Varien_Db_Select
     */
    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $this->_renderFilters();

        $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

        $countSelect->columns('COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id)');
        $countSelect->resetJoinLeft();

         //  $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)'); // original code
        if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) { // handles group by. from stackoverflow
            $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            //$countSelect->distinct(true);
            $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
            $countSelect->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")"));
            $countSelect->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id)'));
        } else { // if no group by, handle the original way
            $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
        }
        return $countSelect;
    }
}
```

And here's the one for the attribute resource:

```
/**
 * Catalog Layer Attribute Filter Resource Model
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Catalog
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mynamespace_MyModule_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Layer_Filter_Attribute extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Layer_Filter_Attribute
{
/**
     * Retrieve array with products counts per attribute option
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute $filter
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCount($filter)
    {
        // clone select from collection with filters
        $select = clone $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getSelect();
        // reset columns, order and limitation conditions
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);

        $connection = $this->_getReadAdapter();
        $attribute  = $filter->getAttributeModel();
        $tableAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_idx';
        $conditions = array(
            "{$tableAlias}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
            $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.attribute_id = ?", $attribute->getAttributeId()),
            $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.store_id = ?", $filter->getStoreId()),
        );


            $select
                ->join(
                    array($tableAlias => $this->getMainTable()),
                    join(' AND ', $conditions),

                array('value', 'count' => "COUNT(DISTINCT IFNULL(e.custom_grouping,e.entity_id))"))

                ->group("{$tableAlias}.value");

        /*  $select // ORIGINAL CODE
            ->join(
                array($tableAlias => $this->getMainTable()),
                join(' AND ', $conditions),
                array('value', 'count' => "COUNT({$tableAlias}.entity_id)"))
            ->group("{$tableAlias}.value");
        */
            if(isset($_GET['testing'])) {   // 20140111 by Nick to see if this code is executing
                $_SESSION['called'][] = 'File ' . __FILE__ . ' - Line: ' . __LINE__ . 'getcount sql: ' . (string)$select;
            }
        return $connection->fetchPairs($select);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your customizations should be as easy to maintain as possible - especially for upgrades. This is likely best accomplished by identifying the best integration points and customizing core functionality when necessary.

When you rewrite a class via the configuration, you are changing the class instantiated, assumedly to customize a *part* of some core class behavior. This is more appropriate from a programmatic standpoint than owning the *entire* definition.

Rewrites won't work for parent classes or for library classes (e.g. `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`), so changes to these *must* be implemented by transferrance to local code pool. I'm very curious to know what you want to change with the DB collection superclass.

While blocks, helpers, and models all have a similar xpath for rewriting, e.g.

```
global>[blocks|helpers|models]>[class group]>rewrite>[class id]
```

resource models require a slightly different mapping. I can tell you are using a pre-MDBM release of Magento (CE <1.6), so your rewrite mappings would be as follows:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer_filter_attribute></layer_filter_attribute>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        <catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
            <rewrite>
                <layer_filter_attribute></layer_filter_attribute>
                <product_collection></product_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
    </models>
</global>
```

As I said, I am *quite* curious to know your reasons for rewriting the resource models.

Comment: Ok, it turns out that `Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php` was not one of the files with a class I need to override. I needed a change to `getSelectCountSql()` and it did not work in `Db.php` because the function is overridden in `Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php`. So scratch that part.
I'm only changing 1-2 methods maximum in each of the php files.

Comment: I've added my config.xml. I feel like making a module *IS* the most efficient way of making my changes, rather than having a slurry of various changes all over the local structure. I don't know what the best integration point is but the 3-4 changes I've made to have the intended effect at least. And a module can be easily deactivated or reactivated, while a bunch of changes in `local` file structure cannot.

Comment: If your module does not have any blocks of its own instantiated via `mynamespace_mymodule` then you don't need that node.

Comment: I've updated with Xpaths to use.

Comment: I put in the bodies of the overridden resource classes. Perhaps I'm doing things in an extremely improper way. I'm not satisfied with the built-in configurable products. So I made my own version.