# Show Simple Product's Title and SKU in Cart when ordering Configurable

Tags: attributes

I'm trying to find a solution to modify the items ordered in shopping cart, when user selects cofigurable product then select color swatch of simple product, trying to show the simple product title/sku in cart instead of the parent configurable product title on this website http://buymydrap.com/cotton/cotton-dinner/ecru-cotton-dinner-napkin.html

I've done a work around to where it's showing the options info in front of the config. product title, but this is confusing for the customer and admin, so i'm trying to keep the color swatch feature as is with config. and simple product setup, but want to have the order and invoice only show the simple product color /sku at checkout.

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:** This only partially answers your question, but it will allow you to display the simple product name (as a working link to the
>   configurable product) and the simple product sku in the cart. This
>   solution will also display the simple product name in the minicart
>   (sidebar).
>
> For my answer I will be using the Magento CE 1.9.1.0 Default Package and build in Configurable Swatches
>   module. I noticed that you are using the Amasty Color Swatches extension for your
>   store. So you may have to edit different files to achieve the same result.
>
> As always, make sure you have a proper backup of your Magento file
>   system and database before making any changes.

This is where we start from (Configurable Product Name with Options displayed in Cart):

[image: Configurable Product Name in Cart]

1. Copy the file

   ```
   app/code/CORE/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/Configurable.php
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/code/LOCAL/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/
   ```
2. Open the file and from line 81 replace

   ```
       /**
        * Get item product name
        *
        * @return string
        */
       public function getProductName()
       {
           return $this->getProduct()->getName();
       }
   ```

   with

   ```
       /**
       * Get item product name
       *
       * @return string
       */
      public function getProductName()
      {
          if ($option = $this->getItem()->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
              return $option->getProduct()->getName();
          }
          return $this->getProduct()->getName();
      }

      /**
       * Get item sku
       *
       * @return string
       */
      public function getProductSku()
      {
          if ($option = $this->getItem()->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
              return $option->getProduct()->getSku();
          }
          return $this->getProduct()->getSku();
      }
   ```

   Save and close the file.
3. Copy the file

   ```
   app/design/frontend/BASE/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/template/checkout/cart/item/
   ```
4. Open the file and from line 42 replace

   ```
   <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
   <dl class="item-options">
       <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
       <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
       <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
       <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
           <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
           <div class="truncated_full_value">
               <dl class="item-options">
                   <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                   <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
               </dl>
           </div>
           <?php endif; ?>
       </dd>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </dl>
   <?php endif;?>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <?php echo $this->getProductSku() ?>
   ```

   Save and close the file.

The result should look something like this (Simple Product Name with Simple Product Sku in Cart):

[image: Simple Product Name in Cart]

When I find some time I may try to address the second part of your question (order confirmation and invoice) as well. But maybe this will help you to figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually override the Mage Core block instead of copying it in my local folder because in that way you would mask all the new Magento features in this block.

See [how to rewrite core blocks in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10748/how-to-override-core-catalog-block-product-list).