# how to show products order by attribute, Attribute created from admin panel?

Tags: attributes, magento-1, product-collection

I created an attribute sorting order (attribute code : shortorder ) for arrange/sorting(ASC or DESC) the products by adding value to this attribute while adding the products.

In the list.phtml product collections are collect by

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();.
```

Is there any way to do this shorting in product view page?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to override the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` block, specifically, its `function _getProductCollection()` to implement the necessary filtering.

A proposed override for the function `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection:`

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{ 
    $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('attribute code', 'asc');
    $this->_productCollection = $collection;

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @liyakath.
i am using getLoadedProductCollection() function.

Comment: thats not concern,it is ok this function is called after my above function you can see `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`

Comment: $liyakath am confused to where i want add this?

Comment: refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10748/how-to-override-core-catalog-block-product-list