# Set a limit on the maximum price of a product?

Tags: php, price

is it possible to only show products £1000 or under across an entire shop?  Or is there custom XML code you can apply on a per category basis?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a filter in product collection like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('price',array('from' => 0, 'to' => 1000))
                     ->setPageSize(5000);
```

**EDIT:**

You should rewrite `Catalog/Block/product/List.php` to custom `_getProductCollection()` method.

Follow this link: [How to override core catalog block product list?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10748/how-to-override-core-catalog-block-product-list)

Comment: Many thanks Price.  I tried this in list.php where there is a reference to 

$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

Am I editing the wrong file?

Comment: You can find the list.phtml in app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: yeah got the right file, but do I replace 

 $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); with your code or change the reference to $collection in your code to $_productCollection ?

Comment: No, you can't add my code in a phtml, you should rewrite a block who prepare a collection of this list.phtml on your local then you add a filter price in that collection.

Comment: Look my answer, then validate the answer if you see that it helped you.

Comment: Thanks Prince, I copied out that file to Local and added your code under $collection = $this->_getProductCollection(); on line 142, but i then loose the toolbar and it lists all products in that category and still shows products over £1000.

All of these products have Group Prices so would it be final_price i need to filter on not price?

Comment: do getData() on you object then get you price attribute

Comment: Please validate my answer if you see that it helped you.